# npm installing hundreds of packages

Tags: npm

npm now installs a package-lock.json every time which seems to be a part of npm now. However, this simple package.json file when run with npm install installs over 300 packages. what could be going wrong and why are there 300+? even without the package-lock file when run (it then creates the lock file) and still gives 300+ packages

```
{
  "name": "Package",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.2",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compress": "^1.4.3",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^1.0.2",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^2.2.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^3.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-sass": "^2.1.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "^3.1.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's expected. Your dependencies have dependencies, who likely have dependencies (etc).

Comment: You can use a tool like https://npm.anvaka.com to see more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those packages depend on other packages, which depend on other packages, which depend on yet other packages…. A package manager resolves that entire dependency graph, which can easily grow into the hundreds from an innocent-looking initial list.

The `package-lock.json` file you mention can help you understand how this happens for your particular dependencies. Look for `"requires"`. For example, in your setup, `grunt-sass` requires `node-sass`:

```json
"grunt-sass": {
  "version": "2.1.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-sass/-/grunt-sass-2.1.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-XkexnQt/9rhReNd+Y7T0n/2g5FqYOQKfi2iSlpwDqvgs7EgEaGTxNhnWzHnbW5oNRvzL9AHopBG3AgRxL0d+DA==",
  "dev": true,
  "requires": {
    "each-async": "1.1.1",
    "node-sass": "4.9.0",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1"
  }
},
```

…which has 19 separate dependencies:

```json
"node-sass": {
  "version": "4.9.0",
  ...
  "requires": {
    "async-foreach": "0.1.3",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "cross-spawn": "3.0.1",
    "gaze": "1.1.3",
    "get-stdin": "4.0.1",
    "glob": "7.0.6",
    "in-publish": "2.0.0",
    "lodash.assign": "4.2.0",
    "lodash.clonedeep": "4.5.0",
    "lodash.mergewith": "4.6.1",
    "meow": "3.7.0",
    "mkdirp": "0.5.1",
    "nan": "2.10.0",
    "node-gyp": "3.6.2",
    "npmlog": "4.1.2",
    "request": "2.79.0",
    "sass-graph": "2.2.4",
    "stdout-stream": "1.4.0",
    "true-case-path": "1.0.2"
  },
  ...
}
```

…and just one of those, `request`, itself introduces another 20:

```json
"request": {
  "version": "2.87.0",
  ...
  "requires": {
    "aws-sign2": "0.7.0",
    "aws4": "1.7.0",
    "caseless": "0.12.0",
    "combined-stream": "1.0.6",
    "extend": "3.0.1",
    "forever-agent": "0.6.1",
    "form-data": "2.3.2",
    "har-validator": "5.0.3",
    "http-signature": "1.2.0",
    "is-typedarray": "1.0.0",
    "isstream": "0.1.2",
    "json-stringify-safe": "5.0.1",
    "mime-types": "2.1.18",
    "oauth-sign": "0.8.2",
    "performance-now": "2.1.0",
    "qs": "6.5.2",
    "safe-buffer": "5.1.2",
    "tough-cookie": "2.3.4",
    "tunnel-agent": "0.6.0",
    "uuid": "3.2.1"
  }
},
```

You can see how it gets to 300 so quickly.